# How can I add text to a Label without overwriting?

Tags: java, javafx, label

I want to add text to a `Label` in JavaFX without removing the previous text.
I've tries this but it just overwrites all of it:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("Line1");
label.setText("Line2");
```

For instance, if I want it to say "Line1Line2". Is there no other way than the following:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("Line1");
label.setText("Line1Line2");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the previous label, concatenate it with a new part and then set a whole text:

```
label.setText(label.getText() + "Line2");
```

There are no other ways since we have access only to a getter/setter; API doesn't provide a more convenient method (like a builder/appender).